# New Azure App Service deployment through OneDrive is stuck trying to retrieve a folder

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a new Azure App Service, and I'm setting up OneDrive for deployment.

After choosing a OneDrive account, I'm stuck on the second page where it is trying to get a folder. It's stuck with the spinning icon, and I'm not able to continue.

UPDATE:

I gave up on using OneDrive for deployment and instead went to Azure DevOps.

Comment: Did you try a different browser or in private browsing mode?

Comment: Tried it in Chrome (including incognito mode) and Safari. Still getting stuck on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the following steps:

- In the Azure Portal > Navigate to your WebApp.
- Go to the Deployment Center blade.
- Select Onedrive and then select “Change Account” to reauthenticate.
- If that is successful, select another Source Option (E.g GitHub or
  FTP), and then reselect Onedrive.
- Check to see if the folder list populates now.